# Adding a button to the support ActionBar

Tags: android, user-interface, android-activity, menu, android-actionbar

I currently have this setup for my application in which I have an action bar at the top of the screen with a "hamburger" icon in the top left that shows this navigation drawer.
[image: Navigation drawer in the application]

I now want to add an icon in the top right of the action bar which will display a cart with a badge. Unfortunately, I don't seem to have found a viable solution, as most what I've seen answered for other questions seems outdated. In particular, what I've tried is adding another menu option that has "app:showAsAction" set to always and having it "setup" by overriding  `onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)`  in my activity. The problem is that 1. The item is also displayed in the navigation drawer, which I do not want 2. This creates an option menu, which means I get the presence of these permanent three dots:
[image: Action bar with undesired option menu]

I'd like to know about an alternative solution that lets me both have a navigation drawer with a regular "hamburger" icon in the action bar on the left and a cart button (button, not just an icon, I need to have behavior on click) in the top right. This is what my project looks like:

menu_entries.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   android:id="@+id/navMenu"
   tools:ignore="HardcodedText">
   <item
       android:id="@+id/navMenuCocktail"
       android:title="Cocktail" />
   <item
       android:id="@+id/navMenuFrullati"
       android:title="Frullati" />
   <item
       android:id="@+id/navMenuSuggested"
       android:title="Suggeriti" />
   <item
       android:id="@+id/navMenuLogout"
       android:title="Logout"/>
   <item
       android:id="@+id/navMenuActionCart"
       android:title="Cart"
       android:enabled="false"
       app:actionLayout="@layout/cart_item_layout"
       android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_cart"
       app:showAsAction="always"/>
</menu>
```

layout_home.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawerLayoutHome"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/progressBarHome"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:scaleX="0.5"
        android:scaleY="0.5"
        android:indeterminateTint="@color/drink_orange"
       />

    <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerViewDrink"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"/>



    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/navViewMenu"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        app:menu="@menu/menu_entries"/>

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

ControllerHome.java (the activity displayed. I commented out a lot of irrelevant things such as networking and navigation drawer logic.)

```
//
public class ControllerHome extends AppCompatActivity implements
        NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    private ArrayList<FeedItem> cartFeedItems = new ArrayList<>();

    private enum HomeState{
        HOME_COCKTAIL,
        HOME_FRULLATI,
        HOME_SUGGESTED,
        HOME_CART,
        HOME_LOGOUT;

        @Override
        public String toString(){
            if (this.equals(HOME_COCKTAIL)) return "Cocktail";
            else if (this.equals(HOME_FRULLATI)) return "Frullati";
            else if (this.equals(HOME_SUGGESTED)) return "Consigliati";
            else if (this.equals(HOME_LOGOUT)) return "Logout";
            else if (this.equals(HOME_CART)) return "Carrello";
            return "INVALID";
        }
    }
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle actionBarDrawerToggle;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private HomeState currentHomeState = HomeState.HOME_COCKTAIL;
   //
    private RecyclerView recyclerViewDrink;
    private FeedItemAdapter feedItemAdapter;
    private ProgressBar progressBar;
    private TextView cartBadge;
    private int numberOfItemsInCart = 0;
    private final int MAX_NUMBER_OF_CART_ITEMS_DISPLAYED = 99;
    private FeedItemAdapter.ProductQuantityListener
            productQuantityListener;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.layout_home);
        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayoutHome);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.navViewMenu);
        recyclerViewDrink = findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewDrink);
        progressBar = findViewById(R.id.progressBarHome);
        actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout, R.string.nav_open, R.string.nav_close);

        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
        actionBarDrawerToggle.syncState();

        getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
        //
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(@NonNull Menu menu){
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_entries, menu);
        MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.navMenuActionCart);
        View actionView = menuItem.getActionView();
        cartBadge = actionView.findViewById(R.id.cart_badge);
        actionView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onNavigationItemSelected(menuItem);
            }
        });
        cartBadge = findViewById(R.id.cart_badge);
        cartBadge.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        productQuantityListener = //
                
        return true;
    }
 
    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {

        if (actionBarDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    //
}
```

Comment: Why are you using the same menu XML file for both the drawer and action bar if you want them to be different menus? You can create more than one XML file

Comment: That is a good point, but that doesn't remove the option button I think

Comment: Did you actually try it?

Comment: That actually did it. My bad, I thought it being an options menu would automatically create the options dropdown.